# How include HTTP request in app.run() in ionic

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I'm made android project with ionic V1. I want make app send some function before app close with [Cordova event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#quick-example). I try use pause  to send data to server but I have stuck in sending data in app.run(). This my code in **app.js**

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) { 
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function () { 
      document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
   }); 
   function onPause($http) {
    $http.get('https://localhost:88/web.php?tN=off&f12=123456789')
    .then(function(response){
         console.log(response);
    }, function(error){
         //there was an error fetching from the server
    });
   }
});
```

And this **error from debugger**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

I don't know where what wrong with this code. I used in `controller.js` it work correctly but in `app.js` it doesn't work. Please help me to solved this problem. Thanks

Comment: The console log errors are a good thing to share too

Comment: at the starting of your code add $http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$http is missing is your run() parameters